# udp_recv cpu usage increase after setting CPU affinity

Tags: c, linux-kernel, udp, affinity

I wrote a simple udp_recv test demo, and I found one strange thing

If I set the CPU affinity to `cpu0`, the cpu usage is 5%, but after setting affinity to other cpu, the cpu usage increased to 9%~12%,especially set to `cpu20`, the cpu usage is more than 25%!

I use `perf -e cpu-lock top -p xxxx` to check the hotpot functions.
When I set affinity to `cpu0`, the cpu usage is 5%, and I got this:

```
Samples: 20K of event 'cpu-clock', Event count (approx.): 742033834  
 20.41%  [kernel]      [k] fget_light
 11.84%  [kernel]      [k] copy_user_enhanced_fast_string
  8.63%  [kernel]      [k] sock_recvmsg
  6.49%  [kernel]      [k] _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore
  5.81%  [kernel]      [k] aa_revalidate_sk
  3.93%  [kernel]      [k] SYSC_recvfrom
  3.85%  [kernel]      [k] sockfd_lookup_light
  3.47%  [kernel]      [k] udp_recvmsg
```

Then I set CPU affinity to `cpu5` , the cpu usage is 10%, and I got this:

```
Samples: 1K of event 'cpu-clock', Event count (approx.): 286637653
 13.33%  [kernel]      [k] copy_user_enhanced_fast_string
 10.51%  [kernel]      [k] _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore
  7.02%  [kernel]      [k] fget_light
  5.55%  [kernel]      [k] system_call_after_swapgs
  4.68%  [kernel]      [k] sock_recvmsg
  4.65%  udp_recv      [.] process_udp_connection(int)
  4.21%  [kernel]      [k] __slab_free
  4.15%  libc-2.15.so  [.] __GI___libc_recvfrom
  4.15%  [kernel]      [k] skb_copy_datagram_iovec
  3.76%  [kernel]      [k] inet_recvmsg
  3.45%  [kernel]      [k] __ticket_spin_lock
  3.19%  [kernel]      [k] udp_recvmsg
  2.91%  [kernel]      [k] SYSC_recvfrom
  2.72%  [kernel]      [k] move_addr_to_user
  2.38%  [kernel]      [k] put_compound_page.part.18
```

Then I set CPU Affinity to `cpu20`, the cpu usage is 27%, And I got this:

```
Samples: 238K of event 'cpu-clock', Event count (approx.): 2529242834
16.81%  [kernel]      [k] copy_user_enhanced_fast_string 
 8.46%  [kernel]      [k] udp_recvmsg
 6.48%  [kernel]      [k] _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore
 4.59%  [kernel]      [k] skb_release_data.part.49
 4.28%  [kernel]      [k] sock_recvmsg
 4.12%  [kernel]      [k] __slab_free
 3.28%  libc-2.15.so  [.] __GI___libc_recvfrom
 3.14%  [kernel]      [k] SYSC_recvfrom
 2.88%  [kernel]      [k] kmem_cache_free
 2.85%  [kernel]      [k] __skb_recv_datagram
 2.71%  [kernel]      [k] inet_recvmsg
 2.71%  [kernel]      [k] system_call_after_swapgs
 2.69%  udp_recv      [.] process_udp_connection(int)
 2.58%  [kernel]      [k] fget_light
 2.03%  [kernel]      [k] skb_free_datagram_locked
 1.92%  [kernel]      [k] skb_release_head_state
```

I observed that function `copy_user_enhanced_fast_string` CPU percentage increased. I think this is the reason.

So why the CPU affinity impact so much?

Comment: What is the CPU you're running this on? Have you tried moving your process to different cores with `sched_setaffinity()`?